# Does Stone's theorem works with a pseudometric?

Tags: general-topology

Basically I don't know if a pseudometric space is paracompact.

I thought in the Stone's theorem but Stone requires a metrizable space, but I check the demostration and which does not use strongly the fact of having a metric. I think the Stone's theorem works with a pseudometrizable space (ie with a pseudometric such that the topology generated by this pseudometric be the original topology of the space).

It is the following correct?

Stone's theorem : Every pseudometrizable space is a paracompact space.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct (unless you’re one of those odd folks who include Hausdorffness in the definition of paracompactness).

Comment: @David: No!! I don´t need the Hausdorffness in the definition of paracompactness.

Thanks